# QWebEngineView history canGoForward/canGoBack works only after three items

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I have a simple application where the back and forward buttons are enabled/disabled based on the history of the visited web pages. For this, I have found the `canGoForward` and `canGoBack` functions
of the `QWebEngineHistory`. However, the functions return True only after there are at least three items in the history. Normally, browsers work right after visiting the second different page.

Is this supposed to be working like that? I there any way to change it to the 2 web pages? I have looked at the `QWebEngineSettings`, but there is nothing related to this.

Here is a working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLineEdit, QMainWindow, 
    QPushButton, QToolBar)
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage, QWebEngineView


class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.toolBar = QToolBar(self)
        self.addToolBar(self.toolBar)

        self.backBtn = QPushButton(self)
        self.backBtn.setEnabled(False)

        self.backBtn.setIcon(QIcon(':/qt-project.org/styles/commonstyle/images/left-32.png'))
        # self.backBtn.setIcon(QIcon('stock_left.png'))
        self.backBtn.clicked.connect(self.back)
        self.toolBar.addWidget(self.backBtn)

        self.forBtn = QPushButton(self)
        self.forBtn.setEnabled(False)
        # self.forBtn.setIcon(QIcon('stock_right.png'))
        self.forBtn.setIcon(QIcon(':/qt-project.org/styles/commonstyle/images/right-32.png'))

        self.forBtn.clicked.connect(self.forward)
        self.toolBar.addWidget(self.forBtn)

        self.address = QLineEdit(self)
        self.address.returnPressed.connect(self.load)
        self.toolBar.addWidget(self.address)

        self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.webEngineView)

        self.webEngineView.page().urlChanged.connect(self.onLoadFinished)

        print(self.webEngineView.history().backItem().url())
        print(self.webEngineView.history().forwardItem().url())

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('QWebEnginePage')
        self.show()

        # self.webEngineView.page().urlChanged.connect(self.urlChanged)

    def onLoadFinished(self):

        print(dir(self.webEngineView.history()))
        print('load finished')
        # print(self.webEngineView.history().backItem().url())
        # print(self.webEngineView.history().forwardItem().url())
        # print(self.webEngineView.history().backItem())
        # print(self.webEngineView.history().forwardItem())
        # print(self.webEngineView.history().count())
        # print(self.webEngineView.history().items())
        # print(self.webEngineView.history().canGoForward())
        # print(self.webEngineView.history().canGoBack())

        if self.webEngineView.history().canGoBack():
            self.backBtn.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.backBtn.setEnabled(False)

        if self.webEngineView.history().canGoForward():
            self.forBtn.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.forBtn.setEnabled(False)


    def load(self):

        url = QUrl.fromUserInput(self.address.text())

        if url.isValid():
            self.webEngineView.load(url)

    def back(self):
        self.webEngineView.page().triggerAction(QWebEnginePage.Back)

    def forward(self):
        self.webEngineView.page().triggerAction(QWebEnginePage.Forward)

    def urlChanged(self, url):
        self.address.setText(url.toString())


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: your example works for me correctly, browsers work right after visiting the second other page.

Comment: I see that it works correctly, could you give a detailed example where it is proven that it does not work.

Comment: @eyllanesc If you enter webcode.me and then zetcode.com; there is no back button yet. Then I have tried different pages, webcode.me and then google.com, it worked right after the second page...

Comment: @JanBodnar When I enter "webcode.me" and right click, the menu appears with the options "Go" and "Back" disabled as expected (remember that initially the page does not have a url), when I enter "" zetcode.com "then if the option "Back" appears enabled because there is already a valid url above. Please use `@username`

Comment: @eyllanesc Are you on Windows? I just tested the example on Windows 10 and it works as expected. On my main machine, which is a Debian derivative, it sometimes does not work after two pages (the toolbar buttons.) Interestingly, the right popup menu options work OK on Linux. I guess, this must be some bug.

Comment: @JanBodnar I have tested it on Linux (Arch Linux) with PyQt5 5.15 and it always works correctly in my case.

Comment: @eyllanesc Then it must be a bug in this particular Linux OS. You can answer it with this resolution and I will accept it.